# Find intersecting coordinates from the same table postgis

Tags: sql, postgis

I currently have two tables one which is for states and holds a unique ID, the state name, and the coordinates of the state.  The second one is for urban areas which holds a unique ID, the urban area name, and the coordinates of that area.  I am trying to find which urban areas intersect each other while excluding self-intersections (meaning if area A intersects area B and area B intersects area A, only return one result, not both)

I currently have the code:

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM urbanTable AS s, stateTable as a 
WHERE ST_Intersects(s.coords, s.coords) 
AND (a.gid != s.gid) 
GROUP BY s.name;
```

However this is not returning the correct amount of results.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is `ST_Intersects(s.coords, s.coords)` correct? Also, you say you want intersecting urban areas? So why are you even using the `stateTable`?

Comment: Yes, by the wording of that post I believe that is incorrect? I had been usually working with checking the intersections of the first AND the second table, this is the first time I have been working with just one table.  The only reason I used both was because my professor said try using the UID to do this.  Which also confused me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `gid` is a unique identifier on `urbanTable`

```
select
    u1.name,
    u2.name
from
    urbanTable u1,
    urbantable u2
where
    u1.gid < u2.gid and -- avoid duplicating results
    ST_Intersects(u1.coords, u2.coords)
```

Comment: WOW thank you very much!.  I obviously want to understand this and not just copy this, so just to make sure I am understanding this correctly.  What this does is checks each result from u1 with a u2 where u2 has a greater gid (to make sure that it is only checked once), then checks for the ones that intersect between the two?

Comment: Yep, `gid1 < gid2` is a trick to to get all distinct pairs from a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo, as you test for `ST_Intersects(s.coords, s.coords)` and not for `ST_Intersects(s.coords, a.coords)`

Comment: the only reason I am even using A was because my professor said try using the UID to do this which maybe he means the UID of only table one and not even including the second table.  However I do not know where this would come into account